# inkscape conversion pdf to eps

Tags: inkscape, pdf, eps, file-conversion

I'm trying to convert a .pdf image into a .eps one. The image quality is good but the font labels are not conserved as shown in the images

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

For the conversion I use the command

> inkscape image.pdf --export-eps=image.eps

Comment: A guess would be that a font substitution is taking place because you don't have that font installed.

Comment: @BillyKerr  The labels are created in Latex. Is there any way to include latex fonts in inkscape?

Comment: To use fonts in Inkscape they must be installed on your computer, in the system fonts folder.

Comment: Another way to proceed might be to convert the text to outlines before exporting as PDF. Not sure if that's possible in LaTeX though.  Maybe something to ask on TeX Stack Exchange.